# Replace fields in columns on click with JS

Tags: javascript, html, spring

I am trying to find a way to do something with JavaScript. I have a list of exercises, they are 5, and I want when I click on one of them, this exactly one to be transferred to another list(right one), this will be the exercises the user choose from the left list, and if he changes his mind, to be able to return this exercise to the left list. Also, when some exercises are chosen, to be visible only on the right site.

```
<ul id="left" th:each="exercise : ${exercises}">
    <button type="submit">
        <li th:text="${exercise.name}">
    </button>
    </li>
</ul>

<ul id="right"  th:each="exercise : ${exercises}">
    <button type="submit">
        <li th:text="${exercise.name}">
    </button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Something like that.
(I build the whole project with Java and Spring)

Answer (score 0):

I assume the 2 lists come from the Back End and are rendered on the UI.

You need to send a request to the server to tell that an item that clicked on to the server "API endpoint" to move the item to the 2nd list

- If you are using ajax you need to send a get request to get the updated lists
- If you are using Spring MVC that will require reloading the View to update the UI

If the lists are built on the Front end and then will be submitted to the server

You need to remove the element from 1st list and then add it to the 2nd list

```
<ul id="left">
 <li id="i" onclick="remove(this)">Item that clicked on</li>
</ul>

<ul id="right">
  <li id="li1">li 1</li>
  <li id="li2">li 2</li>
</ul>


<script>

function remove(el) {
    const textContent = el.textContent;
    // copy classes or id or anything

    el.remove();

    addElementToRightList(textContent);
}

function addElementToRightList(textContent) {
    const parent = document.querySelector("#right");
    const element = document.createElement("li");

    // do stuff with element eg: set text by getting it from item that clicked on using textContent
    element.textContent = textContent;

    parent.appendChild(element);
}

</script>
```

Comment: How can I make it when it is already in the right list, to be clickable and to return to the left list?

Comment: So the same item might exist-duplicated in both lists? If so consider adding `data` attribute to the item to know 

`<ul>
  <li onclick="showDetails(this)" id="owl" data-animal-type="bird">Owl</li>
  <li onclick="showDetails(this)" id="salmon" data-animal-type="fish">Salmon</li>  
  <li onclick="showDetails(this)" id="tarantula" data-animal-type="spider">Tarantula</li>  
</ul>

<script>
function showDetails(animal) {
  var animalType = animal.getAttribute("data-animal-type");
  alert("The " + animal.innerHTML + " is a " + animalType + ".");
}
</script>`